# Julia vs c++ performance almost factor 30

Tags: c++, performance, julia

The Julia program below takes about 6 seconds on my laptop (second test(n)). An equivalent C++ program (using Eigen) only 0.19 s. According to the results I have seen on https://programming-language-benchmarks.vercel.app/cpp, I expected a much smaller difference. What is wrong with my Julia program? I would be very appreciative for hints on how to improve my Julia program.

```
using StaticArrays
using Printf

struct CoordinateTransformation
    b1::SVector{3,Float64}
    b2::SVector{3,Float64}
    b3::SVector{3,Float64}
    r0::SVector{3,Float64}
    mf::SMatrix{3,3,Float64}
    mb::SMatrix{3,3,Float64}
end

function dot(a::SVector{3,Float64}, b::SVector{3,Float64}) 
    a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + a[3]*b[3]
end

function CoordinateTransformation(b1::SVector{3,Float64}, b2::SVector{3,Float64}, b3::SVector{3,Float64}, r0::SVector{3,Float64})
    mf = MMatrix{3,3,Float64}(undef)

    e1::SVector{3, Float64} = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    e2::SVector{3, Float64} = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    e3::SVector{3, Float64} = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

    mf[1, 1] = dot(b1, e1);
    mf[1, 2] = dot(b1, e2);
    mf[1, 3] = dot(b1, e3);
    mf[2, 1] = dot(b2, e1);
    mf[2, 2] = dot(b2, e2);
    mf[2, 3] = dot(b2, e3);
    mf[3, 1] = dot(b3, e1);
    mf[3, 2] = dot(b3, e2);
    mf[3, 3] = dot(b3, e3);
    mb = inv(mf)
    CoordinateTransformation(b1, b2, b3, r0, mf, mb)
end

@inline function transform_point_f(at::CoordinateTransformation, v::MVector{3,Float64})
    at.mf * v + at.r0
end

@inline function transform_point_b(at::CoordinateTransformation, v::MVector{3,Float64})
    at.mb * (v - at.r0)
end

@inline function transform_vector_f(at::CoordinateTransformation, v::MVector{3,Float64})
    at.mf * v
end

@inline function transform_vector_b(at::CoordinateTransformation, v::MVector{3,Float64})
    at.mb * v
end

function test(n)
    theta = 1.0;
    c = cos(1.0);
    s = sin(1.0);
    b1::SVector{3, Float64} = [c, 0.0, s]
    b2::SVector{3, Float64} = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    b3::SVector{3, Float64} = [-s, 0.0, c]
    r0::SVector{3, Float64} = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    at::CoordinateTransformation = CoordinateTransformation(b1, b2, b3, r0)

    @printf("%e\n", n)

    points = Array{MVector{3, Float64}, 1}(undef, n)
    @inbounds for i in 1:n
        points[i] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    end

    @inbounds for i in 1:n
        points[i] = transform_point_f(at, points[i])
    end
    println(points[n])

    @inbounds for i in 1:n
        points[i] = transform_point_b(at, points[i])
    end
    println(points[n])
end


n = 10000000
@timev test(n)
@timev test(n)
```

Comment: May you got the Julia [command line options](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/command-line-options/) wrong?

Comment: Lines like `b1::SVector{3, Float64} = [c, 0.0, s]` create a `Vector` then convert it to a static vector. Create `SVector`s directly (eg by any of the examples from https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl#quick-start).

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, `SMatrix{3,3,Float64}` is an _abstract type_. When used to type a struct field, it harms performance. You have to use `SMatrix{3,3,Float64,9}`. In function signatures and constructors it doesn't matter, but inside struct defs it _does_.

Comment: This `b1::SVector{3, Float64} = [c, 0.0, s]` creates a normal array on the right hand side, and then converts it to an SVector. It is also non-idiomatic in Julia to use type assertions like that. Instead create SVector directly, like this: `b1 = SA[c, 0.0, s]`. Similar thing here: `points[i] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` etc. In general, construct, don't convert.

Answer (score 9):

A major issue with your `test` function is that a massive number of `MVector`s are allocated in the 3 loops. In addition, since `MVector`s are mutable structs, which are reference types, the `points` vector is a vector of references, which is not great for performance.

Instead, I recommend changing `points` to a vector of `SVector`s and modifying the code to accommodate this (e.g., replace every `MVector` with `SVector`). In the first loop, `points[i] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` should be changed to `points[i] = SA[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` to avoid allocations from creating temporary vectors. (See also [Eric's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160451/julia-vs-c-performance-almost-factor-30#comment127498637_72160451) on this.)

Implementing these simple changes, I see an improvement from

```
2.523284 seconds (40.00 M allocations: 1.714 GiB, 43.11% gc time)
```

to

```
0.171544 seconds (267 allocations: 228.891 MiB)
```

Comment: Thank you all a lot. The Julia code now runs as fast as the C++ code.